# ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI is not showing all contacts

Tags: android

I have this method returning all contacts with a given group ID :

```
    public ArrayList<ContactEntity> getContactListByGroup(String groupID) {

        if (groupID != null) {
            ArrayList<ContactEntity> contacts = new ArrayList<ContactEntity>();
            Uri groupURI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID};

            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    groupURI,
                    projection,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
                            + "=" + groupID, null, null);

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID));
                contacts.add(getContactByID(id));
            }

            return contacts;

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I add a contact manually on the phone, it doesn't return the new contact. But if I add it by an `applyBatch` (code side), this method returns the new contact as expected.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: your groupURI is probably wrong...

Comment: groupURI is actually ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, that's the only way I found to get all contacts from a specific group...